# Body field not saving it's summary data

Tags: 7, entities

I've inherited a Drupal 7 site that was built in 2014. We've noticed that the body field (on any content type) has a summary textarea, but it does not save data upon submission.

Also, in comparing with other D7 sites that we have, I find it odd that on this site the Body field is assigned a 'Long text' field type whereas normally the body field uses a 'Long text and summary' field type.

Also of note, the 'Summary input' check-box on the content type setting page (/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/body) does not exist.

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the body field widget to **Long text and summary**

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: this could be a form alter hook implementation. It would explain why the summary (or a summary) field appears even though the configuration is only for a long text.

Try looking at the site's custom modules for a hook_form_alter implementation.

Cheers